# HTML text with underline has unexpected appearance with attributed string in version iOS 14

Tags: html, swift, swift5, ios13, ios14

I am trying to use the HTML as the content of UILabel but getting a weird issue in iOS 14 that the underline color is getting changed as per the text color.

**I am using the following code**

1. ViewDidLoad

   ```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()

                    lblHtml2.htmlText = """
                                   <p><span style="text-decoration:underline">I am facing<span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold"> error </span>in version <span style="color:darkolivegreen;font-weight:bold">of greater than 14 </span> for wrong underline color.</span></p>
                                      """
                }
   ```

I am using this extension to format the HTML into an attributed string:

```
 extension UILabel {
        
        var htmlText: String? {
            get {
                do {
                    if let attrText = attributedText {
                        let data = try attrText.data(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrText.length),
                                                     documentAttributes: [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html])
                        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                    }
                } catch {
                    // Fall through
                    
                }
                
                return text
            }
            
            set {
                guard let html = newValue, !html.isEmpty else {
                    self.text = nil
                    return
                }
                
                do {
                    
                    let attributedString = try html.htmlToAttributedString(pointSize: font.pointSize, color: textColor, direction: "rtl")
                    
                    self.attributedText = attributedString
                } catch {
                    self.text = html
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    



extension String {

  enum Errors: Error {
      case AttributedStringConversionError
  }

  func htmlToAttributedString(pointSize: CGFloat = UIFont.labelFontSize, color: UIColor = .black, direction: String = "ltr") throws -> NSAttributedString {
    let fontedHTML = #"""
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            rt {
                display: inline
            }

            body {
                font-size: \#(pointSize)px;
                font-family: 'system-ui';
                color: \#(fontColor(color: color));
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div dir="\#(direction)">\#(self)</div>
    </body>

    </html>
    """#
    
    let data = Data(fontedHTML.utf8)
    
    guard let attrText = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) else {
        throw Errors.AttributedStringConversionError
    }
    
    
    if !attrText.string.isEmpty && attrText.string.hasSuffix("\n") {
        return attrText.attributedSubstring(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrText.length - 1))
    } else {
        return attrText
    }
}

private func fontColor(color: UIColor) -> String {
    var red: CGFloat = 0
    var green: CGFloat = 0
    var blue: CGFloat = 0
    var alpha: CGFloat = 0
    color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
    return "rgba(\(Int(red * 255)), \(Int(green * 255)), \(Int(blue * 255)), \(alpha))"
 }
}
```

correct display in iOS 13 :[Expected behavior][1]
incorrect display in iOS14 : [Current Behavior][2]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK6Co.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Pzz.png

Comment: Looks like a bug in UILabel. I'd suggest to use UITextView as a possible workaround. Another option might be to implement the formatting solely with NSAttributed sting attributes.

Comment: @ScorpiCon yes , works well with UITextView . So is there a bug while using UILabel ?? 
also UILabel works well with iOS 13 ...